# Custom save method in django model and login issue

Tags: python, django

I have written a custom save method for my model:

```
class UserProfile(User):
      sex = models.SmallIntegerField(verbose_name=_(u'Sex'), choices=SEX_TYPES, default=1)
      .
      .


     def save(self, **kwargs):
         if self.pk is not None:
             UserSettings.objects.create(
                 user_id = self.pk
             )
         super(UserProfile, self).save(**kwargs)
```

and:

```
class UserSettings(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('userprofile.UserProfile', verbose_name=_(u"User"), related_name='own_user', null=True, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.id)
```

This custom method create a `UserSettings` object (in register). But after [`login`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.login), another `UserSettings` creates. 
How can I avoid this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`get_or_create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create):

```
def save(self, **kwargs):
    settings, created = UserSettings.objects.get_or_create(
        user_id=self.pk
    )
    super(UserProfile, self).save(**kwargs)
```